# I want to fetch the date timestamp in Toad using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I have a column in toad

CREATE_DATE='10/9/2020 2:05:10 AM'

I am trying to fetch this using the below SQL Query but it is giving me an error ''Not a valid Month'.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
CREATE_DATE = '10/9/2020 2:05:10 AM'
```

can someone please help, how can i fetch this column

'

Comment: Toad doesn't have columns.  It is a GUI that interfaces to databases.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a `DATE` datatype column. If that's so, here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (create_date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate);

1 row created.
```

Just to see what's in there:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From test;

CREATE_DATE
-------------------
09.10.2020 09:15:12
```

OK; now, use a query which utilizes the `TO_DATE` function (as we'd want to provide a **string** to it) with appropriate format mask (so that Oracle knows *what is what* in that string; whether `09` represents a month, or a day).

For example:

```
SQL> select * from test
  2  where create_date = to_date('09.10.2020 09:15:12', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

CREATE_DATE
-------------------
09.10.2020 09:15:12
```

Or, another date format (the one you use):

```
SQL> select * from test
  2  where create_date = to_date('10/9/2020 9:15:12 am', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am');

CREATE_DATE
-------------------
09.10.2020 09:15:12
```

Basically, the *keyword* is to let the database know what you **exactly** want, not let it *guess*. Sometimes it'll succeed, but sometimes it'll fail - just like in your query.

Comment: 'let Oracle know' - BUT question is tagged mysql..?

Comment: Uh, is it? Filter showed this question because of the TOAD tag, didn't even notice that. Thank you, @P.Salmon.

Comment: But still, it shouldn't really matter. Database should know what you want; maybe there are different functions' names, but the principle is the same.